# MS Graph Explorer: How to use GraphServiceClient object to get a specific user's drive

Tags: c#, graph, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to figure out how to programmically get a specific folder for a specific user.
In Graph Explorer I can do something like this to get the drive ID

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<specificUsersGuid>/drive/root/children
```

And then I follow up with this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<specificUserGuid>/drive/items/<driveId>/children
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this programmatically using c#.  I found this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples

and it has an example of how to use the "me" syntax for the current user, I guess?  But I need a way to specify the user.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Graph API SDK then you can use `Users["{id}"]` to get `GraphServiceUsers` request builder.

The first request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<specificUsersGuid>/drive/root/children
```

can be written as

```
var driveItemChildrenCollectionPage = await graphClient.Users["specificUsersGuid"].Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

The second request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<specificUserGuid>/drive/items/<driveId>/children
```

as

```
var result = await client.Users["specificUsersGuid"].Drive.Items["driveItemId"].Children.Request().GetAsync();
```